# Polynomial Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

There is a class called Polynomial with a Node class and the Node class consist of a term class that it self contains the coefficient and degree of the respective polynomial. So there are two objects, p polynomial and this polynomial, these are linked list of Nodes with each node having a term object (containing data on degree and coeff.). I am given p Polynomial and this polynomial and must use them to build newPoly which is an object that contain a linked list of Nodes with each node containing a term object. I must return the newPoly object. When ran, my code does not show the new added polynomial in which I return. Please help me.

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        Polynomial x = this;
        Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial ();
        Polynomial y = p;


        while (x.poly.next != null || y.poly.next != null){

            Node ptr = null;

            if (x.poly.term.degree == y.poly.term.degree ){
                /*ptr.term.coeff = x.poly.term.coeff + y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = x.poly.term.degree;*/
                ptr = new Node (x.poly.term.coeff+y.poly.term.coeff,x.poly.term.degree, newPoly.poly);
                //ptr.next = newPoly.poly;

                y.poly = y.poly.next;
                x.poly = x.poly.next;

            }else if (x.poly.term.degree>y.poly.term.degree){


                ptr.term.coeff = x.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = x.poly.term.degree;

                ptr.next = newPoly.poly;
                /*
                Polynomial ptr2 = new Polynomial();
                ptr2.poly.term.coeff = y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr2.poly.term.degree = y.poly.term.degree;

                ptr2.poly.next = newPoly.poly;
                */
                x.poly = x.poly.next;


            }else if (x.poly.term.degree<y.poly.term.degree){

                ptr.term.coeff = y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = y.poly.term.degree;

                ptr.next = newPoly.poly;


                y.poly = y.poly.next;

            }else {
                if (x.poly.next == null){
                    float coef = x.poly.term.coeff + y.poly.term.coeff;
                    int exp  = x.poly.term.degree;

                    x.poly = x.poly.next;
                    y.poly= y.poly.next;
                    if (coef == 0) continue;

                    ptr = new Node(coef, exp, null);

                }

            }

        }

        return newPoly;
    }
```

---

//Whole Polynomial class code
    package poly;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * This class implements a term of a polynomial.
 * 
 * @author runb-cs112
 *
 */
class Term {
    /**
     * Coefficient of term.
     */
    public float coeff;

    /**
     * Degree of term.
     */
    public int degree;

    /**
     * Initializes an instance with given coefficient and degree.
     * 
     * @param coeff Coefficient
     * @param degree Degree
     */
    public Term(float coeff, int degree) {
        this.coeff = coeff;
        this.degree = degree;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other != null &&
        other instanceof Term &&
        coeff == ((Term)other).coeff &&
        degree == ((Term)other).degree;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString() {
        if (degree == 0) {
            return coeff + "";
        } else if (degree == 1) {
            return coeff + "x";
        } else {
            return coeff + "x^" + degree;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This class implements a linked list node that contains a Term instance.
 * 
 * @author runb-cs112
 *
 */
class Node {

    /**
     * Term instance. 
     */
    Term term;

    /**
     * Next node in linked list. 
     */
    Node next;

    /**
     * Initializes this node with a term with given coefficient and degree,
     * pointing to the given next node.
     * 
     * @param coeff Coefficient of term
     * @param degree Degree of term
     * @param next Next node
     */
    public Node(float coeff, int degree, Node next) {
        term = new Term(coeff, degree);
        this.next = next;
    }
}

/**
 * This class implements a polynomial.
 * 
 * @author runb-cs112
 *
 */
public class Polynomial {

    /**
     * Pointer to the front of the linked list that stores the polynomial. 
     */ 
    Node poly;

    /** 
     * Initializes this polynomial to empty, i.e. there are no terms.
     *
     */
    public Polynomial() {
        poly = null;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a polynomial from an input stream (file or keyboard). The storage format
     * of the polynomial is:
     * <pre>
     *     <coeff> <degree>
     *     <coeff> <degree>
     *     ...
     *     <coeff> <degree>
     * </pre>
     * with the guarantee that degrees will be in descending order. For example:
     * <pre>
     *      4 5
     *     -2 3
     *      2 1
     *      3 0
     * </pre>
     * which represents the polynomial:
     * <pre>
     *      4*x^5 - 2*x^3 + 2*x + 3 
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param br BufferedReader from which a polynomial is to be read
     * @throws IOException If there is any input error in reading the polynomial
     */
    public Polynomial(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String line;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        float coeff;
        int degree;

        poly = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            coeff = Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken());
            degree = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            poly = new Node(coeff, degree, poly);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns the polynomial obtained by adding the given polynomial p
     * to this polynomial - DOES NOT change this polynomial
     * 
     * @param p Polynomial to be added
     * @return A new polynomial which is the sum of this polynomial and p.
     */
    public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        Polynomial x = this;
        Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial ();
        Polynomial y = p;


        while (x.poly.next != null || y.poly.next != null){

            Node ptr = null;

            if (x.poly.term.degree == y.poly.term.degree ){
                /*ptr.term.coeff = x.poly.term.coeff + y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = x.poly.term.degree;*/
                ptr = new Node (x.poly.term.coeff+y.poly.term.coeff,x.poly.term.degree, newPoly.poly);
                //ptr.next = newPoly.poly;

                y.poly = y.poly.next;
                x.poly = x.poly.next;

            }else if (x.poly.term.degree>y.poly.term.degree){


                ptr.term.coeff = x.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = x.poly.term.degree;

                ptr.next = newPoly.poly;
                /*
                Polynomial ptr2 = new Polynomial();
                ptr2.poly.term.coeff = y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr2.poly.term.degree = y.poly.term.degree;

                ptr2.poly.next = newPoly.poly;
                */
                x.poly = x.poly.next;


            }else if (x.poly.term.degree<y.poly.term.degree){

                ptr.term.coeff = y.poly.term.coeff;
                ptr.term.degree = y.poly.term.degree;

                ptr.next = newPoly.poly;


                y.poly = y.poly.next;

            }else {
                if (x.poly.next == null){
                    float coef = x.poly.term.coeff + y.poly.term.coeff;
                    int exp  = x.poly.term.degree;

                    x.poly = x.poly.next;
                    y.poly= y.poly.next;
                    if (coef == 0) continue;

                    ptr = new Node(coef, exp, null);

                }

            }

        }

        return newPoly;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the polynomial obtained by multiplying the given polynomial p
     * with this polynomial - DOES NOT change this polynomial
     * 
     * @param p Polynomial with which this polynomial is to be multiplied
     * @return A new polynomial which is the product of this polynomial and p.
     */
    public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates this polynomial at the given value of x
     * 
     * @param x Value at which this polynomial is to be evaluated
     * @return Value of this polynomial at x
     */
    public float evaluate(float x) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        return 0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString() {
        String retval;

        if (poly == null) {
            return "0";
        } else {
            retval = poly.term.toString();
            for (Node current = poly.next ;
            current != null ;
            current = current.next) {
                retval = current.term.toString() + " + " + retval;
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//main
package poly;

import java.io.*;

public class Polytest {
    static BufferedReader br1, br2;
    static Polynomial p1, p2;

    public static final int ADD = 1;
    public static final int MULTIPLY = 2;
    public static final int EVALUATE = 3;
    public static final int QUIT = 4;

    public static int getChoice() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(ADD + ". ADD polynomial");
        System.out.println(MULTIPLY + ". MULTIPLY polynomial");
        System.out.println(EVALUATE + ". EVALUATE polynomial");
        System.out.println(QUIT + ". QUIT");
        System.out.print("\tEnter choice # => ");
        return (Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine()));
    }

    public static void add() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter the file containing the polynomial to add => ");
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(br1.readLine()));
        p2 = new Polynomial(br2);
        System.out.println("\n" + p2 + "\n");
        System.out.println("Sum: " + p1.add(p2) + "\n");
    }

    public static void multiply() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter the file containing the polynomial to multiply  => ");
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(br1.readLine()));
        p2 = new Polynomial(br2);
        System.out.println("\n" + p2 + "\n");
        System.out.println("Product: " + p1.multiply(p2) + "\n");
    }

    public static void evaluate() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter the evaluation point x  => ");
        float x = Float.parseFloat(br1.readLine());
        System.out.println("Value at " + x + ": " + p1.evaluate(x) + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the polynomial file => ");
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(br1.readLine()));

        p1 = new Polynomial(br2);
        System.out.println("\n" + p1 + "\n");

        int choice = getChoice();
        while (choice != QUIT) {
            if (choice < 1 || choice > QUIT) {
                System.out.println("\tIncorrect choice " + choice);
            } else {
                switch (choice) {
                case ADD: add(); break;
                case MULTIPLY: multiply(); break;
                case EVALUATE: evaluate(); break;
                default: break;
                }
            }
            choice = getChoice();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: PS I am willing to pay money for help on this. I need to learn this anyways.

Comment: Can you assume that the linked list of terms in both polynomials is ordered by degree?

Comment: Yes, you can assume the linked list of terms is ordered by degree. From the largest degree n to the smallest degree 0 I believe. It will always be ordered, so that the higher terms will be "first" in the linked list order, it will be from greatest to smallest. Makes things a lot easier.